# How create CocoaPod with dependency?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using the skeleton generated by command `pod lib create`.

I want create a pod that depend two others pods: `PromiseKit` and `AWSS3`. Then, I change the Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'ruawss3_Example' do
  pod 'ruawss3', :path => '../'
  pod 'AWSS3'
  pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 4.0'

  target 'ruawss3_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
    pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase'
    pod 'Nimble-Snapshots'
  end
end
```

And use `pod install`:

```
➜  Example git:(master) ✗ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `ruawss3` from `../`
Downloading dependencies
Using AWSCore (2.4.16)
Using AWSS3 (2.4.16)
Using FBSnapshotTestCase (2.1.4)
Using Nimble (5.1.1)
Using Nimble-Snapshots (4.4.0)
Using PromiseKit (4.1.0)
Using Quick (1.0.0)
Using ruawss3 (0.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.
➜  Example git:(master) ✗ pwd
/Users/brunomacabeusaquino/ApenasMeu/Dropbox (BEPiD)/Swift/ruawss3/Example
```

And add this pods in project:
[image]

But, I can't compile the file in Pods > Development Pods > ruawss3 > ruawss3 > Classes > AmazonS3.swift.
Xcode can't find module 'AWSCore'. How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem.

The correct place to add pod's dependency is in `.podspec` file, using the build settings [dependency](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency). Then, to execute `pod install`.

Comment: I have a `MyProject.podspec` and no `Podfile`. In the podspec, I declared my dependencies. When I run `pod install`, I get `[!] No Podfile found in the project directory.`. Any ideas?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth no

Comment: Apparently you need the pods dependencies in both the `.podspec` and in `Podfile`, at least according to this article https://ronakshah.org/How-To-Make-A-Cocoapod-With-Dependencies